# Migrate: Create term(s) if they do not yet exist

Tags: 8, migrations

Question [similar to this question here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277482/create-migration-stubs-of-entities-for-a-multiple-value-reference-field), but this time, I am not doing a separate migration later.

I want to create taxonomy terms if they do not exist while processing a record. Does `entity_lookup` do this in the same way `migration_lookup` does for stubbing? In this case, I won't be doing another migration to fill in a stub, but surely there must be a way to create a term and keep going.

I don't see anything in `entity_lookup`s plugin indicating it will create if not found.

Comment: Use `entity_generate`, it is basically lookup + generate if not exists [Doc](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-process-plugins-provided-by-migrate-plus)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, ok, getting better at parsing the docs/code for migrate plus. I found it as soon as I posted. The `entity_generate` plugin will do this behavior.

```
  field_paper_jel_codes:
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: jel_codes
```

Now I have a system full of taxonomy.